# overflow-y: scroll doesn't work for dynamic content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I am trying to populate a div dynamically. (***This is being tested for IE9.***) I am trying to use overflow-y: scroll for this div and fixing the max height to 300px. Overflow-y:scroll works if the page is static. It doesn't if my page is dynamic. I understand that the static part is parsed first and the php populates the data later. But how can I get the scrollbar working in this case? Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#menu_items
{
width:45%;
display:inline;
float:left;
max-height:300px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "menu_items">
<table border = "1">
<?php
//$q = $_GET["q"];
//include 'config.php';
//$sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM db WHERE id = '%s'",$q);
//$result = mysql_query($sql);
$number = 35;
for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Name-id</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I understand that the static part is parsed first and the php populates the data later.` You understand it wrong. PHP will not add content "later". Browser will receive all HTML in one piece, both "static" (html, body) and all TRs generated by PHP in for loop (as far as I can see, there is no AJAX here). If that is simplified example, you may need to show your exact code. It looks like generated HTML is broken somehow.

Comment: I have not used ajax here. Plus, if you could save the extension as .php it will show a proper output.

Comment: Now I'm confused completely. It should have PHP extension (by default). Otherwise it will not be handled by PHP engine.

Comment: Hey, i am not able to upload a screenshot. But if you copy this code in a file and save it as index.php and run it, you would see only a gray part instead of a scrollbar. Sorry if I did not communicate well earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the css `height` property instead of `max-height` and check the difference in results.